# Gerd Faltings Interview

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I wanted to read about Gerd Falting's journey as a mathematician . I was searching for a link having his interview but unable to find any . Can anyone here suggest any link for Gerd Falting's interview ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to look at this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jyJma2bPEM

But I think his opinion on his old doctoral student is more interesting
[image]

http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/math-mystery-shinichi-mochizuki-and-the-impenetrable-proof/

Comment: +1 Interesting article about Shinichi Mochizuki. I think it is scandalous that researchers in the field, funded by taxpayers, have not made more effort to understand his proof. :)